# How do I get my integer arithmetic into a long long?

Tags: c

As part of exercise 2-3 in Ritchie and Kernighan's C programming language, I've written a program that converts hexadecimal inputs into decimal outputs. I want it to be able to handle larger numbers, but it seems to be doing integer arithmetic somewhere. When you enter something like "DECAFCAB" it spits out a large negative int. I figured out that I need to add the "LL" suffix to my literals, which I did, but it's still not working. Any help please? Sorry if this is a dumb question or a typo, but I've been at it for an hour and can't figure it out. :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LINE 1000 

void getline(char s[])
{
    int i;
    char c;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_LINE-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n%s", s);
}

long long htoi(char s[]) // convert the hex string to dec
{
    long long n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if(s[i] == '0') // eat optional leading Ox or OX
        ++i;

    if(s[i] == 'x' || s[i] == 'X')
         ++i;

    while(s[i] != '\0')
    {
        if((s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
            n = 16LL * n + (s[i] - '0'); // here is the arithmetic in question
        else if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i]<= 'F')
            n = 16LL * n + (s[i] - 'A' + 10LL);
        else if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f')
            n = 16LL * n + (s[i] - 'a' + 10LL);
        else {
                printf("\nError: Encountered a non-hexadecimal format: the '%c' character was unexpected.", s[i]);
                printf("\nHexadecimal numbers can begin with an optional 0x or 0X only, and contain 0-9, A-F, and a-f.\n\n");
                return -1;
             }
        ++i;

    }
    return n;
}

main()
{
    char input[MAX_LINE];
    long long hex_output;

    while(1){
        getline(input);
        hex_output = htoi(input);
        if(hex_output >= 0)
        printf("\nThe value of the hexadecimal %s is %d in decimal.\n\n", input, hex_output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, hexadecimal values are considered "unsigned" (think of memory addresses that are only positive values)... Accumulating values into a "signed" integer is not going to end well...

Comment: _Side note:_ `getline` is the name of a `libc` standard function. So, I'd rename yours to avoid a collision (e.g. `lineget` or `get_me_an_input_line`). Also, note that because you don't pass down the length of the buffer to [your] `getline`, it has to hardwire the length (e.g. `MAX_LINE`). You could do: `void lineget(char *s,size_t max_line)` and call it (in `main`) with `lineget(input,sizeof(input));`

Comment: PS: `getchar()` returns an `int` that can be compared to `EOF`... Funny that no-one has mentioned this as yet... More "datatype width" confusion in this question... Funny, to me, what qualifies as a proper answer...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Can you explain the problem with getchar() and EOF? I am using it that way because that's how it's written in example programs from the book.  As far as the answer, I accepted his because it was the only answer at the time, I appreciate all of the extra info you've provided.

Comment: @Fe203 I forgot to mention it in my comment, but i changed yours to the accepted answer.

Comment: EOF is defined as -1. As a one byte value, that would preclude using the full 0-255 possibilities of some character sets... `getchar()` can return signed (single byte) values 0-255 as characters, with the signed value -1 held in reserve as a special flag meaning EOF... In short, EOF is _outside_ the range of possibly useful byte values that getchar() can return... (Once tested that the returned integer value is _not_ EOF, it is safe to truncate any hi bytes and only use the low-order byte as a single char...)

Comment: I noticed... Thank you... I believe it to be a better answer to your predicament.

Comment: @Fe2O3 So I should declare c as an int and that fixes it. That's actually what the book was doing, I just forgot to do it because I've been switching between C++ and C so I get confused.  Thank you again Iron Oxide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing comes from treating a (conventionally) "unsigned" hexadecimal integer value as "signed". Resorting using to a larger built-in data type will get you past the problem with going from 31 to 32 bits, but this masks the actual problem. (If you extend to 64 bits, you will encounter the same problem and be back asking, "why doesn't this work.")

Better is to write code that doesn't require ever wider registers. There will always be a maximum width, but the answer to this OP is to use an "unsigned long".

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long htoi( char s[] ) { // convert the hex string to dec
    unsigned long n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if(s[i] == '0') // eat optional leading Ox or OX
        ++i;

    if(s[i] == 'x' || s[i] == 'X')
        ++i;

    for( ; s[i]; i++ ) {
        unsigned int dVal = 0; // don't copy/paste complex statements. 
        if((s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
            dVal = s[i] - '0'; // simple

        else if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i]<= 'F')
            dVal = s[i] - 'A' + 10; // simple

        else if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f')
            dVal = s[i] - 'a' + 10; // simple

        else {
            // less verbose
            printf("\nError: '%c' unexpected.", s[i] );
            return 0; // NB: Notice change!!
        }
        n = (16 * n) + dVal; // simple...
    }

    return n;
}

int main() {
    // simplified, stripping out user input.
    char *hexStr = "0xDECAFCAB";
    unsigned long hex_output = htoi( hexStr );

    // Notice the format specifier to print an ordinary (unsigned) long
    printf( "\nThe value of the hexadecimal %s is %u in decimal.\n\n", hexStr, hex_output );

    return 0;
}
```

```
The value of the hexadecimal 0xDECAFCAB is 3737844907 in decimal.
```

When K&R wrote the original book, there was no such thing as "long long", but there was "unsigned long".

Answer (score 3):

You told `printf` to expect an `int` when you made the placeholder `%d`. To make it expect (and therefore read the entirety of a) `long long`, modify it to `%lld`.

The reason it looks like a plain `int` is that with varargs functions like `printf`, it doesn't *know* what the argument sizes are, and the format string is the only way to figure it out. When you say to expect plain `int`, it reads `sizeof(int)` bytes from the argument, not `sizeof(long long)` bytes (it's not necessarily byte-oriented, but that's how much data is read), and (on a little endian system with 4 byte `int` and 8 byte `long long`) you see (roughly) the result of the argument with the top 4 bytes masked off.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Always having some kind of brain fart over here. :D